# Table is not creating with TIMESTAMP in mysql automatically

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to create a table that contains some post data as well as post date.but problem is all the columns are creating automatically except the **'post_date'** columns that will contains the post date. My code is given below.....

```
$comment_table='CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pppp`
            (
            `initial` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `course_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `course_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `post` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT "empty",
            `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
             `post_date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
            PRIMARY KEY(`post_id`)
            )';
mysqli_query($con,$comment_table);
```

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me out with this. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Typos:

```
         `post_date` [..snip...] CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
                                                  ^--- 
        PRIMARY KEY(`post_id`)
        )';
```

you're terminating your create query early with that "extra" `;`, causing the entire query to be invalid.

If you'd had even minimal error checking on your query call, you'd have been told about the syntax error:

```
mysqli_query($con,$comment_table) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Never **EVER** assume success. You get kicked in the rump by this exact situation. Always assume failure, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.